# Need value in regex.match group

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I want to match regex such that the sign(+ or -) in one group and figure in other group. It may possible that figure comes without any sign(+ or -)

Example

```
 [-] 87.90
 [+] 87.78
 (-) 87.90
 (+) 87.78
  89
 -89.56
 - 89.98
```

I have used below regular expression

```
^\W*(\-|\+|)\W*(\d+(\.\d+)?)
```

By this I am getting empty in group 1
If I use

```
^\W*(\-|\+)\W*(\d+(\.\d+)?)
```

then 3rd figure will not match. So in short I want to match figure with (+ or -) or without any sign.

Comment: does you parenthesis have to be captured as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group 1 is empty because the `\W*` greedily matches all non-word characters, that is, all parentheses and signs.

You should specify the literal parentheses in the pattern and a character class will be a more natural construct to match either a `+` or a `-`:

```
(?:\(?([-+])\)?)?\p{Zs}*(\d+(\.\d+)?)
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3a%5c(%3f(%5b-%2b%5d)%5c)%3f)%3f%5cp%7bZs%7d*(%5cd%2b(%5c.%5cd%2b)%3f)&i=(-)+87.90%0d%0a(%2b)+87.78%0d%0a-89.98%0d%0a89) (if you need a full string match, use `^` at the start and `$` at the end of the pattern).

Regex matches:

- `(?:\(?([-+])\)?)?` - an optional non-capturing group (`(?:...)`) that matches a `(` optionally, followed by a plus or minus (Group 1), and then by an  optional `)`
- `\p{Zs}*` - zero or more whitespace symbols
- `(\d+(\.\d+)?)` - (Group 2) one or more digits followed by an optional capturing group (Group 3) that matches a period followed by one or more digits.

Result:

[image]

Comment: I have edited my question. if the value is -89.98 then this will not work.

Comment: Just make the `(` and `)` optional inside Group 1: `(?:\(?([-+])\)?)?`. Another way to do it: `(?:\((?<symbol>[-+])\)|(?<symbol>)[-+])?`.

Comment: True, but If there is a case like [-] 89.76 then also it should match that's why I have taken \W*

Comment: Are there any more requirements? Please add them to the question. And try [`(?:\W?([-+])\W?)?\p{Zs}*(\d+(\.\d+)?)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3a%5cW%3f(%5b-%2b%5d)%5cW%3f)%3f%5cp%7bZs%7d*(%5cd%2b(%5c.%5cd%2b)%3f)&i=(-)+87.90%0d%0a(%2b)+87.78%0d%0a-89.98%0d%0a%5b-%5d+87.09%0d%0a%5b%2b%5d+87.09%0d%0a89). Another possible regex: `(?:\p{Ps}*([-+])\p{Pe}*)?\p{Zs}*(\d+(\.\d+)?)` where `\p{Ps}` is opening punctuation and `\p{Pe}` is closing one.